# Make Gradle NOT use a source set directory as Eclipse source folder

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have an extra java source set in my build, called `gen` - as in generated sources with lots of compiler warnings in them. The `gradle eclipse` task configures the source directory of this set as eclipse source folder, which leads to a lot of warnings I don't want to see. Another reason is, that the generated source code should not be changed - I don't want somebody to edit it by accident, thinking it is a regular code.

The following works, but only when overwriting existing configuration with `gradle eclipse`.

```
eclipse.classpath.file {
    whenMerged { classpath ->
        classpath.entries.removeAll { 
            entry -> entry.kind == 'src' && entry.path == 'src/gen/java'
        }
    }
}
```

However, it does not work if the configuration is cleaned - `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse` , which is what happens when you first import the project in eclipse.

Reading the [EclipseClasspath object documentation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html), I figure that the only other way is to use `eclipse.classpath.file.withXml` , but it seams too messy to edit the raw xml.

Is there any other more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar scenario by adding the 'gen' directory to the main java sourceSet.

As follows

```
configurations {
 jaxb
}

dependencies {
  jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:'
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs 'gen'

task createGenDirs() {
  file("gen").mkdirs()
}

task jaxb << {
  dependsOn createGenDirs

  //generate src into gen directory

}

task cleanGeneratedCode(type: Delete) {
  delete file("gen")

clean.dependsOn cleanGeneratedCode
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I achieved this (in my case, the source folders were merged and only packages differed):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            exclude 'com/foo/generated/**'
        }
    }
    // This sourceset is ignored by Eclipse
    gen {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            include 'com/foo/generated/**'
        }
    }
}
// Include in a real build from Gradle rather than Eclipse
compileJava {
    source sourceSets.gen.java
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse doesn't know about generated source that other code is using, then you might end up with compiler *errors* in Eclipse instead.

But maybe if there was a source directory that gradle was using to create a 2nd jar, or something like that. If you have that stuff as a separate source set, then you can exclude that from eclipse:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDir 'src' }
    }
    gen {
        java { srcDir 'src-gen' }
    }
}
eclipse {
    classpath {
        sourceSets -= [sourceSets.gen]
    }
}
```

I have a slightly different situation where my project file references another project's source, so I don't want any code to show up in Eclipse:

```
sourceSets.main.java { srcDir '../other_project/src' }
eclipse {
    classpath {
        // remove the source set from the Eclipse classpath
        sourceSets -= [sourceSets.main]
    }
    // Don't let the src dir show up as a linked folder either
    project {
        file {
            withXml {
                def res = it.asNode().get('linkedResources')[0]
                res.link.findAll{ it.name[0].text() == 'src' }.each{     
                    res.remove(it) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```